# stencilJS 4.11 export types for Angular 16.2

Tags: angular, typescript, web-component, stenciljs

My components in StencilJS have props.

For example, a bit of code from my button component :

button.tsx

```
import { ButtonColors } from '../../../interfaces';

@Component({
  tag: 'ap-button',
  styleUrl: 'button.scss',
  shadow: true,
})
export class APButton {

  @Prop() color: ButtonColors = 'primary-500';
  ...
```

Notice the ButtonColors custom type for the color prop

Interfaces.ts
`export type ButtonColors = 'primary-500' | 'secondary-500';`

When I import my stencil components in Angular 16.2 I'm not able to get these types.

For example in app.component.html, I'm using a button but impossible to see the list of possibles values for the prop color

I'm looking for a way to include this interfaces.ts file into my web component package but for now It's a fail.

Any idea ?